# Where does beamer use the headline template?

Tags: beamer

I've been digging through the internals of beamer's frame creation code, trying to customize a theme I created. My goal was to suppress the display of the page number on slides where the frame option `noframenumbering` is given. But that's not my question. In the process of figuring out how to do it, I spent quite some time tracing through internals like `\beamer@@@@frame` to see where it actually used the `headline` template, and *that's* what I can't figure out.

Here is a summary of what I *think* I've figured out so far. (And bear in mind I'm not overly familiar with TeX so I will probably misuse terms like "calls.") In my main document, I might use the `\frame` command, or `\begin{frame}`. Either way, execution eventually winds up in the macro `\beamer@framecommand`. That in turn calls `\beamer@frame`, which calls `\beamer@@@frame`, which in turn calls `\beamer@@@@frame`.

It seems like the typical execution path through `\beamer@@@@frame` ends with

```
 % buried within conditionals
 \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@doseveralframes
% ...
\beamer@howtotreatframe
```

So then I go to look at the definition of `\beamer@doseveralframes`, and that amounts to

```
% stuff
\def\beamer@doifinframe{%
  \begin{beamer@frameslide}%
    #1%
  \end{beamer@frameslide}%
}
% stuff
```

Then I look at the environment definition for `beamer@frameslide` earlier in the file. I see that it creates the box `\beamer@frametitlebox` to store the frame title, and then uses it in

```
\setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox{%
  \nobreak\vbox{}\nobreak\par\nobreak\beamer@entrycode\nobreak%
  \nointerlineskip\unvbox\beamer@frametitlebox%
  % etc.
}
% ...
\beamer@undolabels
\beamer@framenotesend
\box\beamer@framebox
```

OK, so this is where the `frametitle` template is used (?), but I don't see anything about `headline`, even despite checking into the definitions of many of the macros I left out of these quick code snippets.

Approaching this from the other end, the only place I see where the `headline` template is used is within

```
\def\ps@navigation{%
  \def\@oddhead{%
    % stuff
    \beamer@typesetheadorfoot{headline}%  (effectively \usebeamertemplate***{headline})
    % other stuff
  }%
}
```

But I don't see that `\ps@navigation` or `\@oddhead` get used anywhere, only defined. What's the missing link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracing what `beamer` does is like trying to untangle overcooked spaghetti. However, `grep` can provide some places to start:

`beamer.cls`:

```
\RequirePackage{beamerbaserequires}
```

`beamerbaserequires.sty`:

```
\RequirePackage{beamerbaseframecomponents}
```

`beamerbaseframecomponents.sty`:

```
\def\ps@navigation{
```

This is defining a new page style - like `plain` or `empty`. The name of the style is `navigation`. Defining `oddhead` just is essentially telling LaTeX what to put in the header on odd-numbered pages or on all pages if the document is single-sided.

And:

```
\pagestyle{navigation}
```

Says to use this as the default page style.

EDIT: Note that I did this backwards with `grep` and then reversed the order of results to trace `beamer`'s usage forwards from the class file.

Comment: That makes sense. The key piece I was missing was the builtin meanings of `\ps@navigation` and `\@oddhead`. If that information is out there elsewhere online, it seems to be rather well hidden.

Comment: @DavidZ Yes, I figured that was the piece you were missing since you had traced the stuff within beamer to that. But I thought a complete (ish) 'path' might be helpful to others. I'm not sure about an online source for that info. I think I picked it up from Kopka & Daly's *A Guide to LaTeX* (2nd ed.) but that was a long time ago! The section on creating a customised layout for letters covers these commands, if I remember correctly.